# leaflet geojson contextmenu

Tags: contextmenu, leaflet, geojson

I want to add a context menu on right click for various elements on my geojson layer (I'm doing a road map so on a right click on the road at any part I want to show the context menu).

I've managed to get the left click working fine by using the onEachFeature and doing the following

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {
        layer.on({
            click: showAssetInfo,
            contextmenu: contextreg
        });

    }   

 function showAssetInfo(e) {
        AssetMouseClick(e.target.feature.properties.objectid, e.latlng);
    }
```

For the context menu I have followed the example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Q3L4c/12/)  . The context menu library is found [here](http://medialize.github.com/jQuery-contextMenu/)

I have the following that gets called on the document ready (jquery)

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: 'path.leaflet-clickable',
    zIndex: 99999,
    callback: function (key, options) {
        var m = "clicked: " + key;
        window.console && console.log(m) || alert(m);
    },
    items: {
        "edit": { name: "Edit", icon: "edit" },
        "cut": { name: "Cut", icon: "cut" },
        "copy": { name: "Copy", icon: "copy" },
        "paste": { name: "Paste", icon: "paste" },
        "delete": { name: "Delete", icon: "delete" },
        "sep1": "---------",
        "quit": { name: "Quit", icon: "quit" }
    }
});
```

I've tested it and the selector does return the GeoJson features, also if it attach the same menu to something else it works correctly.

Is there something I am missing here?

Also is there a good way to pass in the objectid to the menu when it starts up so I can use it when calling the different options of the menu

EDIT:

I have created this fiddle to demonstrate http://jsfiddle.net/Q3L4c/22/

Comment: Any luck? Please update if you managed to get it working. Thanks

Comment: sorry just ended up using the leaflet popups instead

Comment: Thanks, and I ended up using custom div, on clicked points.

Answer (score 2):

There is a good leaflet plugin for context menu that was created in Aug 2013:
[Leaflet.contextmenu](https://github.com/aratcliffe/Leaflet.contextmenu)

This context menu library has great documentation including step-by-step instructions for implementation in GeoJSON layers.

In the following code snippet, notice how we can easily pass through the full feature and layer objects to the function that is called when the edit menu item is selected. In this example the layer group is a GeoJSON layer group, the GeoJSON properties can be accessed via `feature.properties`

> **NOTE:** In this solution content menu item definitions are generated during the `onEachFeature` processing, not dynamically when the context menu is invoked, just something to be aware of if your were planning on dynamic menu item generation which might be dependent on variables that could change at run time, you need to evaluate the visibility or enabled option for each item as a static value when you create the menu item.

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {

    layer.bindContextMenu({
        contextmenu: true,
        contextmenuInheritItems: false,
        contextmenuItems: [
            { text: 'edit', icon: 'edit', callback: function () { editFeature(feature, layer); } },
            { text: 'cut', icon: cut', callback: function () { console.log('cut'); } },
            { text: 'copy', icon: 'copy', callback: function () { console.log('copy'); } },
            { text: 'paste', icon: 'paste', callback: function () { console.log('paste'); } },
            { text: 'delete', icon: 'delete', callback: function () { console.log('delete'); } },
            { separator: true },
            { text: 'quit', icon: 'quit', callback: function () { console.log('quit'); } },
        ]
    });

    layer.on({
        click: showAssetInfo
    });

}   

/**
 * Edit a feature on the map
 * @param {GeoJSON} feature GeoJSON feature, access metadata through feature.properties
 * @param {any} layer Leaflet layer represents this feature on the map (the shape)
 */
function editFeature(feature, layer) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(feature.properties));
}

function showAssetInfo(e) {
    AssetMouseClick(e.target.feature.properties.objectid, e.latlng);
}
```